# Using rider and visual studio for the same project?

Tags: visual-studio, csproj, rider

I work on a dotnet project in rider. My colleague works on the same project and prefers visual studio. The project contains a lot of test fixtures (thousands). Rider tries to index all those files, which I don't need. So I exclude the test file folder from the index. What rider does is it adds one line per file in the excluded folder to the .csproj file:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Folder Include="excludedDir\subdir1\" />
  <Folder Include="excludedDir\subdir2\" />
  <_ContentIncludedByDefault Remove="excludedDir\file_0001.xml" />
  ...
  <_ContentIncludedByDefault Remove="excludedDir\file_9999.xml" />
</ItemGroup>
```

That seems to solve the indexing problem for rider. But Visual Studio cannot handle a .csproj file that is 10'000 lines long. Just opening the project takes 5 minutes at best. So working on that project with that .csproj file is not an option anymore.

Has anyone ever had a similiar issue and found a solution to:

- making VS ignore the `_ContentIncludedByDefault` keys
- or excluding files from rider index without having rider specify each file individually?

Comment: I think I can help you. But I have to know what is '_ContentIncludedByDefault' items. Can you make a sample project? I think Rider just have to completely ignore all these files. Are they visible in the solution explorer also?

Comment: No, the files are not visible in rider's solution explorer. Rider adds those lines

<_ContentIncludedByDefault Remove="excludedDir\file_9999.xml" />

to the .csproj file in order to know which files not to index and I need VS to ignore them. VS trying to process those is the problem and leads to a completely unresponsive VS whenever I try to open such a project.

Comment: Could you create maybe a sample project? I will investigate and fix Rider for you =)

Comment: @xtmq there's same problem described - https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/4242

Comment: @AlexanderGoldabin Thank you, I'll track that.